# Lazy loading of before/after image slider in each modal

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, lazy-loading

I'm using this to open/close the modal and add lazy loading to the images, problem is that no matter which modal i open all the images are loaded.

```
  var thumb = document.querySelectorAll(".thumb");
        var modal = document.querySelectorAll(".modal");
        var exit = document.querySelectorAll(".close");
        var imgEl = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

        for (var i = 0; i < thumb.length; i++) {
            thumb[i].onclick = function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                modal = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute("href"));
                modal.classList.add("activemodal");
                modal.classList.remove("outmodal");
                setTimeout(function () {
                    document.body.classList.add("over")
                }, 350);

                for (var i = 0; i < imgEl.length; i++) {
                    if (imgEl[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
                        imgEl[i].setAttribute('src', imgEl[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
                        imgEl[i].removeAttribute('data-src');
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < exit.length; i++) {
            exit[i].onclick = function () {
                for (var index in modal) {
                    modal.classList.remove("activemodal");
                    modal.classList.add("outmodal");
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        document.body.classList.remove("over")
                    }, 350);
                }
            }
        }
```

EDIT as a workaround i've set the modal to be 150vh under the screen and moved them before the "in" animation triggers. Doing so the intersection observer does its job.

If you still come up with a better solution i'm glad to learn, can't really get my head around how to link each image with the current modal.

Comment: First thing is you’re using a nested for loop with both having an index called i

Comment: Why not use the intersectionObserver API to initiate the lazy loading? You can read about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: because it's not working in a reliable way, the modal are at the bottom of the document and once opened are displayed fullscreen with position fixed.

I already have a script for lazy loading imgs and background images and it's not working on the ones in the modals.